# ifelse() in R else value remains the same

Tags: r, if-statement

Packages: tidyr, dplyr, openxlsx, ggplot2, data.table

AMT = amount

I have this as my ifelse so far:

`df_dose_DT$AMT <- ifelse(df_dose_DT$AMT==-99, doseIV2 * df_dose_DT$WTKG * df_dose_DT$DT, )`

**Notice:** the blank space for the 'else' section of the code. I want these values to remain unchanged, as they have already been assigned. I have purposely assigned AMT to -99 for only very specific data points.

I can't just use the if command, because if I do something like this:

`df_dose_DT$AMT <- if(df_dose_DT$AMT==-99) doseIV2 * df_dose_DT$WTKG * df_dose_DT$DT`

It does not retrieve the whole equation used to calculate amount for only the values that have -99, everything else needs to remain the same.

I want the else command just to be ignored in away that allows me to calculate the AMT.

So what would I put here:

`df_dose_DT$AMT <- ifelse(df_dose_DT$AMT==-99, doseIV2 * df_dose_DT$WTKG * df_dose_DT$DT, {here})`

Thank you in advance :).

Comment: `df_dose_DT$AMT`. Using a simpler example, `a_thing = 1:3; a_thing = ifelse(a_thing == 2, 12345, a_thing)`

Comment: So the values are based on a calculation, would they remain the same for individual rows as they were, or would they all change to the same value if that was the else?

Comment: @Jon Spring Thank you sir, my mind totally blanked and went for more complex ideas, and the solution was so simple. - Thanks again.

Comment: Another example, take a look: `a_thing = 1:4; a_thing = ifelse(a_thing %in% c(1,4), a_thing * 100, a_thing); a_thing`